# ajax request always going through else

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I've been trying to validate a login form, this is my ajax code:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {
/* Asociar el evento de clic del botón 'igual'
   con la lógica del negocio de la aplicación */

    $('#formlogin').submit(function() { 
        procesar();
        return false;
    });
});

function procesar() {
    var data = 'usuario=' + $('#usuario').val() + '&contrasenia=' + $('#contrasenia').val();
    $.ajax ({     
        url:  'postlogin.php', /* URL a invocar asíncronamente */
        type:    'post', /* Método utilizado para el requerimiento */
        data:     /* $('#formulario').serialize()*/data, /* Información local a enviarse con el requerimiento */

/* Que hacer en caso de ser exitoso el requerimiento */

        success:  function(response) {    
            if((response) == ""){    
                window.location = "./home";    
            }else{
                $('#mensaje').html(response);
            }      
        },

/* Que hacer en caso de que sea fallido el requerimiento */

        error:  function(response) {   

/* Limpiar cualquier resultado anterior */

            $('#mensaje').html('Error de subida');
        } 
    });
}       

</script>
```

and this is my php file:

```
<?php

include('libreria.php');
$conn= conectar();

if(isset($_POST["usuario"])){
    $resulusuario= verificarusuario($_POST["usuario"], $_POST["contrasenia"], $conn);

    if($resulusuario->num_rows==0){
        echo "ERROR: usuario o contraseña ingresados incorrectos";    
    } else{ 

        session_start();    
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];           
    }
}else{
    if(isset($_POST["mensaje"])) {    
        cargartweet($_POST["idusuario"], $_POST["mensaje"], $_POST["fecha"], $conn);    
    } else {    
        if(isset($_POST["nombreusuarioseguir"])) {    
        }    
    }
}
?>
```

any ideas why it's always going through else of the ajax success?, I mean, even if the username and the password it's ok, it won't redirect me, and the worst thing it's that yesterday it was working...

Comment: `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Have you at least tried to debug this yourself?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I already tried to debug, but when the username it's ok, it just goes through else condition of the success

Comment: There might be any kind of empty line or " " in your response. What you can try is using: if(trim(response) == ""){ ...

Answer (score 0):

The response never equals `""`.  It's that simple.  You need to do something like `console.log(response==="");` and you will see this for yourself.  It will be false.  The response might be `" "` or any number of things.  There is an appropriate test to run, but you need to find out what `response` equals that is not `""`.

Comment: yes, you were right, response it's not "" or " ", but I'm not sure what other thing could be..

Comment: alert (response); will tell you what it is and might help you find the error

Comment: the alert shows a blank message, maybe I should ask for a null return on the if

Comment: You could test it like `if /^\s*$/.test(response){...` would find a response of only spaces.  I would go back to the server and find what (and why) is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

i think your var data values usually for GET method, Try array:

```
var data =  { usuario: $('#usuario').val(), contrasenia: $('#contrasenia').val() };
```

or change type to get and replace $_POST to $_GET.
Good luck